# Creating a Box which is not descendant or the first node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, forest

Is it possible to create a box at the same level as the Children or Grandchildren but not a descendant from the first node (oil wealth)? Think of an isolated box called 'ABC', which does not have an arrow derived from any box above. Thank you

```
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shadows}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[length=2mm]}},
  every edge/.style = {arr}
        }

\usepackage{lipsum}             % for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
\section{Tree}\label{sec6}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=7em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    s sep = 4mm,
    l sep = 13mm,
     edge = {arr},
        }
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners
    [Grandparent 
        [Parent
            [Child 1, name=A1
                [Grandchild]
            ]
            [Child 2, name=A2
                [Grandchild, name=B2]
            ]
            [Child 3
                [Grandchild, name=B3
                    [Grand-Grandchild]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw   (A1) edge (B2)
        (A1) edge (B3)
        (A2) edge (B3);  
    \end{forest}
\caption{Mine Editing Tex III}
\label{fig: Causal}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, you could simply use the `no edge` option for the respective anchor, as shown in the exemplary modification of your code below. Details can be found on pages 44-45 of the `forest` [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf). Hope, this helps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shadows}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[length=2mm]}},
  every edge/.style = {arr}
        }

\usepackage{lipsum}             % for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
\section{Tree}\label{sec6}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=7em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    s sep = 4mm,
    l sep = 13mm,
     edge = {arr},
        }
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners
    [Grandparent 
        [Parent
            [Child 1, name=A1
                [Grandchild]
            ]
            [Child 2, name=A2
                [Grandchild, name=B2]
            ]
            [Child 3
                [Grandchild, name=B3
                    [Grand-Grandchild]
                ]
            ]
            [ABC,no edge]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw   (A1) edge (B2)
        (A1) edge (B3)
        (A2) edge (B3);  
    \end{forest}
\caption{Mine Editing Tex III}
\label{fig: Causal}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much